# Question regarding an implication of the compactness of $S_n(T)$ for countable and complete theory $T$.

Tags: model-theory

Suppose that there is an $n$ such that the set of $L$-formulas in variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ up to $T$-equivalence is finite. That is, there is no finite set of formulas $\{\varphi_i\}_{i\in I}$ (with $I$ finite) such that for all $L$-formulas $\psi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ there is a $i \in I$ such that $$T \models \forall x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n(\psi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \leftrightarrow \varphi_i(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)).$$

Then somehow by the the topological compactness of $S_n(T)$, there must be an non isolated type $p(x)$. My question is how to conclude that from the hypothesis.

I understand that if $S_n(T)$ is compact then for an open cover $\mathcal{C}$ of $S_n(T)$ there is a finite cover $\mathcal{C}'$ of $S_n(T)$, that is if $S_n(T) = \bigcup_{[\varphi] \in \mathcal{C}} [\varphi]$, then $S_n(T)= \bigcup_{[\varphi] \in \mathcal{C}'} [\varphi]$, but from this information I do not know how to obtain a non isolated type $p(x)\in S_n(T)$.

Is there any other property of the compactness of $S_n(T)$ that I am missing? Can you explicitly find the non isolated type, or is the proof by contradiction, i.e. supposing that all types of $S_n(T)$ are isolated and using the fact that the set $\{\varphi_i\}_{i\in I}$ is infinite?

Comment: I edited your post to correct some typos and improve the formatting. The original way the finiteness hypothesis was written was extremely confusing - I've tried to clarify without changing the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove the contrapositive. Suppose every type in $S_n(T)$ is isolated. Then for all $p\in S_n(T)$, $\{p\}$ is open, and $\bigcup_{p\in S_n(T)}\{p\}$ is an open cover of $S_n(T)$. By compactness, $S_n(T)$ is finite.

Now we can write $S_n(T) = \{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$, and since each $p_i$ is isolated, we can find a formula $\varphi_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $[\varphi_i] = \{p_i\}$. For each $S\subseteq \{1,\dots,k\}$, let $\varphi_S$ be $\bigvee_{i\in S} \varphi_i$. Then $[\varphi_S] = \{p_i\mid i\in S\}$.

Finally, for any formula $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, let $S_\psi = \{i\mid p_i\in [\psi]\}\subseteq \{1,\dots,k\}$. Then $[\psi] = [\varphi_{S_\psi}]$, so $$T\models \forall x_1\dots x_n (\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)\leftrightarrow \varphi_{S_\psi}(x_1,\dots,x_n)).$$
Since there are only finitely many formulas of the form $\varphi_S$, this shows that there are only finitely many formulas up to $T$-equivalence.

Comment: Good God! I forgot the fact that a type $p(x)$ is isolated in $S_1(T)$ if and only if $\{p(x) \} =  [\varphi]$ for some L-formula $\varphi$, and as we know every open subset of $S_1(T)$ is equal to $[\psi]$ for some L-formula $\psi$, hence what you have just described!! Thank you very much !!

Comment: @HugoChavez every *clopen* subset is of that form, not every open (but perhaps more importantly here the sets of that form are a base for the open sets).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You are correct my dear fellow! As $S_n(T)$ is 0-dimensional it has a base of clopen subsets.